# How to solve $T(n) = 2T(n/4) + n \log n$ with substitution method?

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I am trying to solve this recurrence with substitution method. I guess $T(n) = \Theta(n \log n)$ (with Master Theoreme). Can someone show me how to demonstrate the upper bound $T(n) = O(n \log n)$?

Answer (score 1):

Use complete induction. The base case is obvious, and here is the induction step:

$$T(n)=\\2T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+n\log(n)\le\\ 2c\cdot\frac{n}{4}\log\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+n\log(n)\le\\\frac{2c}{4}n\log(n)+n\log(n)=\\\left(\frac{2c}{4}+1\right)n\log(n)$$

So by choosing any $c$ such that $\frac{2c}{4}+1\le c$, you can guarantee that $$T(n)\le \left(\frac{2c}{4}+1\right)n\log(n) \le c\cdot n\log(n)$$
As required to show.